# Why is my C program's file output missing the final lines compared with output of the same content to the console?

Tags: c, file-io

I am using the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{   
 int two=0, two2 = 0;
 int cast11, cast12,c1157,c1257;
 static const char filename[] = "clearedacg_filter.txt";
 static const char filename2[] = "FinalVariantReferenceTable_FilterHomVarArcLiverDR_sorted.txt";
 char* chrarray[22] = {"chr1","chr2","chr3","chr4","chr5","chr6","chr7","chr8","chr9","chr10","chr11","chr12","chr13","chr14","chr15","chr16","chr17","chr18","chr19","chrX","chrY","chrM"};    
 FILE *file3 = fopen("AllSNPcounts_filter.txt","w");
 FILE *file4 = fopen("AllSNPcounts_nonhits.txt","w");
 char word[3];
 char temp[] = "chr1";
 char* dp4 = "DP4";
 FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
 unsigned int i,j,k,sum;
 int count = 0;
 int dp4_field = 0;

 FILE *file2;
 file2 = fopen(filename2, "r");
 if ( file != NULL )
 {
  char line[BUFSIZ],line2[BUFSIZ];
  char one[20], three[22], five[100], four[20], four2[20], one2[20], three2[22], five2[100], six[20], six2[20], seven[20], seven2[20];

  fgets(line, sizeof line, file); 
  fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file2);

  while(1)
  {  
   sscanf(line, "%19s %21s %*s %19s %19s %19s %*s %99s", one, three, four, six, seven, five);
   two = atoi(three);
   sscanf(line2, "%19s %21s %*s %19s %19s %19s", one2, three2, four2, six2, seven2);
   two2 = atoi(three2);
   if(!strcmp(temp,one))
   {
    if(!strcmp(temp,one2))
    {
     if(two == two2)
     {
      dp4_field = 0; 
      for(i=5; i < strlen(five);i++)
      {
       sum = 0;
       for(j=i,k=0; k<3;j++,k++)
       {
        *(word+k) = five[j];
       }
       if(strcmp(word,dp4) == 0)
       {
        dp4_field = 1;
        sscanf(five+4+i, "%d,%d,%d,%d",&cast11 , &cast12, &c1157, &c1257);
       }

      }
      if(dp4_field)
      {
       printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n", one2, three2, cast11+cast12, c1157+c1257, four, six, seven, four2, six2 , seven2);
       fprintf( file3,"%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n", one2, three2, cast11+cast12, c1157+c1257, four, six, seven, four2, six2 , seven2);
      }
      if(fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file2) == NULL)
       break;
      if(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL)
       break;
     }

     else if(two > two2)
     {
      fprintf( file4,"%s\t \n", line2);
      if(fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file2) == NULL)
       break;
     }

     else 
     {
      if(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL)
       break;
     }

    }
    else
    {
     count++;
     strcpy(temp,chrarray[count]);
     while(strcmp(temp,one))
     {
      if(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL)
       break;

      sscanf(line, "%19s %21s %*s %19s %19s %19s %*s %99s", one, three, four, six, seven, five);
     }
    }
   }
   else
   {
    count++;
    strcpy(temp,chrarray[count]);
    while(strcmp(temp,one2))
    {
     if(fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file2) == NULL)
      break;
     fprintf( file4,"%s\t \n", line2);
     sscanf(line2, "%19s %21s %*s %19s %19s %19s %*s %99s", one2, three2, four2, six2, seven2, five2);  
    }
   }
  }
  fclose(file);
  fclose(file2);
  fclose(file3);
  fclose(file4);
 }
 else
 {
  perror(filename);
 }
 return 0;

}
```

i am printing on the console and into the file in this code. It is displaying fine on the console but skipping the last few lines like 20 to 40 lines while printing into the file. I could not figure out the problem here.

Comment: My first suspicion was that you were not closing the file, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Probably best to use a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: For future reference, I suggest you read http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple bug which is apparently exiting your program without executing the set of `fclose` calls at the bottom.  You never explicitly flush the output, so it would normally only flush the final buffered content when you close the file streams at the end, but if the program fails (or hangs) then those do not get called.

The console output is apparently flushed automatically for each newline (typical); thus the difference between them.

The real problem, of course, is not the lack of flushing but the bug which causes the program to fail or hang.  If this is something you seriously coded as opposed to a homework or test problem then you should be able to figure out what's wrong or else debug through it and solve it.  I won't do that part for you. ;)

**Added:** But I'll give you a hint:  Arrays are finite, and bad things tend to happen if you access past the end of them.

Comment: @chom, any luck resolving the bug?